# Android FCM not receiving push notifications after sometime

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application published on the Google Play Store for several years. The Push notification system through FCM works correctly in production, but when I publish new versions of my application, push notifications fail.

The tests I am doing consist of compiling a new version, publishing it as a closed beta version, and testing it. After updating the app with the newly published beta version, the notifications and specific sounds for each notification work well, but after a few hours they stop working and I don't receive notifications.

If the device is restarted, the notifications start working again, but after a few hours, they fail again and notifications stop coming (the same error as before).

If the beta version is uninstalled and the production version from Google Play is reinstalled, the notifications work correctly.

This behavior has been replicated on different Android devices with different versions of the operating system.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

We checked if the token was failing or changing, and it wasn't that... We changed Asynctask to Coroutines. We updated the dependencies, reviewed and implemented permissions in the manifest, and updated the notification build